# How to load only necessary data from database using Hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, filtering, criteria

I have following class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "terminal")
public class Terminal {

    @Column(name = "map_lat")
    private Double mapLat; 

    @Column(name = "map_lng")
    private Double mapLng;

    //get and set methods

}
```

Respectively in database I have corresponded table.

I want to write dao method which will return all terminals which will locate within passed radius and center. I know that I can load all objects and filter their in java code  but I want to load only necessary objects. Is it possible? I have method which check that point inside cicrcle or not.

my current dao method:

```
@Override
    public List<Terminal> findInsideCircleActive(double centerLatitude, double centerLongitude, double radius) {
       List<Terminal> allTerminals = findAllActive() ;
       List<Terminal> filteredTerminals = new ArrayList<>();
       for(Terminal terminal: allTerminals){
           if(distFrom(terminal.getMapLat(),terminal.getMapLng(),centerLatitude,centerLongitude) <= radius ){
                filteredTerminals.add(terminal);
           }
       }
        return filteredTerminals;
    }
```

`dist` method realization:

```
private static float distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
        double earthRadius = 6371; //kilometers
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                        Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

        return dist;
    }
```

database shema:

[image]

Comment: Have you wrote any query for that ? Share it with us so that we can help you more.

Comment: @OO7 I have updated topic

Comment: You need to translate your `distFrom()` method into HQL or SQL.

Comment: @JB Nizet Yes, you are right but I have not ideas how to make it. I added dist method relization

Comment: @gstackoverflow you said, you want all terminals within passed center & radius. Is there any field in DB for them ? or there is some special scenario for that ?

Comment: in DB every terminal has coordainates.  passed center & radius always unique

Comment: Will you update ur question with DB schema ?

Comment: @OO7 you can watch update

Comment: @gstackoverflow In your Terminal, there are only 2 fields namely `mapLat` & `mapLng`. But where is the `radius` & `center` ? In `distFrom()` what ur r actually trying to compute ? Will u elaborate more ? I m unable to understand this structure.

Comment: radius and center I pass from application!  From application I pass point and from database want to find nearest point within radius

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by applying criteria to the query and using findByCriteria() instead of list()

Look at this DAO function from one of my projects:

```
@Override
public List<Project> listByOwner(User owner) {
    DetachedCriteria c = DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Projects.class);
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("deleted", false));
    c.add(Restrictions.eq("owner", owner));
    c.addOrder(Order.desc("dateEdit"));
    return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory).findByCriteria(c);
}
```

If your problem is not related to writing a query but rather related that you specifically want to filter longitudes and latitudes then give Hibernate-Spatail a shot. Is was specifically built for that: http://www.hibernatespatial.org